# Debugging data sent by webbrowser

Tags: debugging, browser

Is there a simple way how can I see what data exactly is webbrowser sending to server including header and post data? Preferably some kind of extension/plugin for chromium or firefox?

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: Fiddler! Made by Microsoft. :) Chrome has this built-in using F12, and Firefox has this via the normal web developer toolkit, but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome already brings Developer Tools. You can access them via `Cmd+Alt+I` or `Wrench` -> `Tools` -> `Developer Tools`. A similar tool is available on Firefox as the excellent "Firebug" extension. This one is actually the mother of all those extensions and is the inspiration of all of the currently shipped ones.

Comment: Oh wow, that worked like a charm :). I knew there are some debugging tools included but I thought it's just for debugging JS or inspecting elements. My bad, I should have tried it first.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug (Firefox)
Developer tools, or Firebug Lite (Chrome)

You can analyse the data using the Network profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already tried firebug or chrome developer tools, and didn't find enough details/control, so try this one, for firefox : http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/